# Syntax::sntxf when using ItoProcess

Tags: warning-messages, syntax

The following code gives an error message `Syntax::sntxf`. What is wrong with my code, and how can I fix it?

```
proc = ItoProcess[\[DifferentialD]x[t] == 
   0.2 (2 - x[t]) (1 - x) \[DifferentialD]t + 
    0.1 \[DifferentialD]w[t], x[t], {x, 0}, t, 
  w \[Distributed] WienerProcess[]]
datax = RandomFunction[proc, {0., 20., 0.01}]
ListLinePlot[% , Filling -> Axis, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["Time(t)", Red], 
   Style["Fraction of potential customers", Red]}]

 Show[Map[ListLinePlot[#, PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.2], Thick]],
  Table[RandomFunction[proc, {0., 20., 0.01}, 
       2], {1000}] & Framelabel -> [{Style["Time(t)", Red], 
     Style["Fraction of potential customers", Red]}]
  ]]
```

Answer (score 1):

After minor syntactic corrections:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
SeedRandom[1];
proc = ItoProcess[\[DifferentialD]x[t] == 
    0.2 (2 - x[t]) (1 - x) \[DifferentialD]t + 
     0.1 \[DifferentialD]w[t], x[t], {x, 0}, t, 
   w \[Distributed] WienerProcess[]];
datax = RandomFunction[proc, {0., 20., 0.01}];

ListLinePlot[datax, Filling -> Axis, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["Time(t)", Red], 
   Style["Fraction of potential customers", Red]}]

procs = Table[RandomFunction[proc, {0., 20., 0.01}, 2], {100}]; (* generating only 100 to save time*)

Show[ListLinePlot[#
    , PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.2], Thick]
    , PlotRange -> {0, 1.75}
    , Frame -> True
    , FrameLabel -> {Style["Time(t)", Red]
      , Style["Fraction of potential customers", Red]}
    ] & /@ procs[[1 ;; 10]]  (* plotting even fewer *)
 ]
```

[image]

[image]